# Accessing variable across different cfm pages in Cold Fusion

Tags: scope, coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I have a cfquery resultset that I need to access in different cfm pages of my code. Initially I tried it assigning it to a variable in client scope by serializing it as a json object. But, CF doesn't allow complex data to be assigned in client scope. I tried it assigning to a variable in application scope, but the problem with that is for one user sometimes the value is similar to the other user who is logged into application at the same time.
Can anyone help me with an alternate to achieve this as a client scope variable and application scope variable are out of option.

Comment: Have you looked at the session scope? https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/developing-cfml-applications/using-persistent-data-and-locking/configuring-and-using-session-variables.html - if it's a really large dataset, just run it on each page

Comment: Could you elaborate on what is being stored and why the application scope is not an option?

Comment: @SOS In my application not all the user has access to everything. Like all the students will not be opting for the same electives. That elective subject ids, I am getting from a http call. Then the list of of subject id I am getting, is being used as a query param in cfquery.
So when I assign the result set to application.subject, this variable should contain different subject ids and their details. But when more than one user are logged in, some times they see similar subject ids and details, even though the elective subjects are not the same for all.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you can't just re-execute the queries as needed? Everything comes with a cost - even caching.  Unless you're encountering a specific problem that justifies storing queries somehow, I'd probably just re-run them as needed.

Answer (score 3):

You have to be very careful when storing query data in any scope. You can end up storing an increasing amount of data in these scopes, which consume memory on the server. Without a strategy to purge this data from those scopes (particularly `server`, `application` and `session`), you can negatively impact the performance of the server over time. As your volume of users increases, cached data / memory increases and the performance of the application decreases.

More often than not, I would prefer to just re-run the query as needed on various pages. Create a CFC with a function that contains your query. Pass any relevant data for the query as arguments to the function. Then you can re-use that query on multiple pages.

A great overview of variable scopes in CFML applications:

http://www.learncfinaweek.com/course/index/section/Decision_Making_and_Scopes/item/Scopes/

> - **Application:** Application variables are shared amongst all connected clients for the current named application. This scope is
>   also used for objects instantiated using the singleton pattern. This
>   scope is available across requests for the life of the application,
>   which may terminate on server shutdown, application malfunction, or
>   application timeout.
> - **Session:** Developers use session variables to store a single visitor's data across requests. This scope is only available to the
>   current session, and will persist until server or application
>   termination, or session timeout.

An overview of Components for code reuse: http://www.learncfinaweek.com/course/index/section/Code_Reuse/item/Components

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the query doesn't change, you can use the cachedWithin attribute of cfquery.

```
<cfquery name="getEmployees" datasource="cfdocexamples" cachedwithin="#CreateTimespan(0,0,60,0)#" >
    SELECT FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,EMAIL,PHONE
    FROM EMPLOYEES
</cfquery>
```